# using latex package from github

Tags: packages, installing

Im new to latex, and i want to use a certain pacakage that I found on github:

https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV

for writing my resume.

I don't understand how should i install? where do i put the folder? should i just use the .cls file by putting it in the same sirectory as my "my_cv.tex" file?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: That is correct. For one time uses just place the files in the same folder as your main `.tex` file.